# How do I detect design mode with WinJS?

Tags: expression-blend, winjs

I have bits of javascript that causes problems when viewed in Blend for Visual Studion 2012. I want to have a simple check for design mode so that I can skip the code when viewed in the Blend Design Surface.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tweeted this question and got an answer from my peers really quick.

```
var isInDesignMode = Windows.ApplicationModel.DesignMode.designModeEnabled;
```